# Qt Creator debugger very slow

Tags: macos, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I'm using *Qt Creator* debugger but when I want to inspect the current `this` variable by expanding it from the *Locals and expressions* view, it take quite a long (about 30 seconds) before giving back control.

I noticed the following message in the *Debugger Log* view:

```
3518fetchVariables({"autoderef":1,"context":"","displaystringlimit":"100","dyntype":1,"expanded":["return","inspect","local.this","watch","local"],"fancy":1,"formats":{},"nativemixed":0,"partialvar":"local.this","passexceptions":0,"qobjectnames":1,"stringcutoff":"10000","token":3518,"typeformats":{},"watchers":[]})
(lldb) script theDumper.fetchVariables({"autoderef":1,"context":"","displaystringlimit":"100","dyntype":1,"expanded":["return","inspect","local.this","watch","local"],"fancy":1,"formats":{},"nativemixed":0,"partialvar":"local.this","passexceptions":0,"qobjectnames":1,"stringcutoff":"10000","token":3518,"typeformats":{},"watchers":[]})
bridgemessage={msg="Searching for type QObjectPrivate across all target modules, this could be very slow"},
eERROR: Lldb stderr: error: PlaybackDevice.o DWARF DW_TAG_array_type DIE at 0x0000db86 has a class/union/struct element type DIE 0x0000db92 that is a forward declaration, not a complete definition.
Try compiling the source file with -fno-limit-debug-info or disable -gmodule
```

I'm using:

- *Qt 5.9.2*
- *Qt Creator 4.5.0*
- *OSX 10.12.6*.

**Edit:**

As Kuba Ober suggests I use a debug build of Qt (5.10.0) thanks to this link: [Qt Creator debugger very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076697/qt-creator-debugger-very-slow)

Unfortunately the message has changed to:

```
eERROR: Lldb stderr: error: PlayBackDevice.o DWARF DW_TAG_array_type DIE at 0x0000f43e has a class/union/struct element type DIE 0x0000f44a that is a forward declaration, not a complete definition.
Try compiling the source file with -fno-limit-debug-info or disable -gmodule
```

Comment: It may depend what your `this` variable contains or is it always slow even for simple objects?

Comment: `this` inherits `QObject`. If `this` is a simple object, it expands very quickly.

Comment: Note the following message in the logs: `"Searching for type QObjectPrivate across all target modules, this could be very slow"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having the same issue. What fixed it for me was unticking "Show QObject names if available" in QtCreator Preferences -> Debugger -> Locals & Expressions.

Comment: you saved me :)

Comment: Ah, finally I can use the Qt Creator debugger without pulling out my hair!

Answer (score 3):

You're not using a debug build of Qt, I presume. While this "bug" is annoying, it does in effect force you to use a debug build of Qt to debug your projects. It should make you way more productive - many problems are easier to fix when you can meaningfully step into the Qt code.

Comment: Sounds promising. Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: For information I have installed Qt from https://www.qt.io/ and I compiled my project in a debug configuration.

Comment: Debug builds of Qt are generally on you - for full debug information you need the trifecta: debug binaries, debug symbols, and source code. In practice, not being set up to compile Qt is a big hindrance. qt.io downloads are I think targeted to beginners and student labs. Once you're serious about it, using those binaries is way more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: How can I get them?

Comment: Ok it seems everything is well explained here: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Comment: Thanks for the information, compiling Qt myself has definitely increased the speed of the debugger. You should add the following link to your answer: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the problem despite using the debug build...

Comment: In fact I have a different message now: `eERROR: Lldb stderr: error: PlayBackDevice.o DWARF DW_TAG_array_type DIE at 0x0000f43e has a class/union/struct element type DIE 0x0000f44a that is a forward declaration, not a complete definition.`

Comment: `Try compiling the source file with -fno-limit-debug-info or disable -gmodule`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and they were mostly resolved by changing my compiler to be the Clang in the same directory as the `lldb` I was using. (Incidentally, that Clang's filename is `gcc`.)